# Docusign integration with spring Application

Tags: docusignapi

I want to integrate docusign with spring application.

Is there any REST Api available?

I got java sdk for docusign but I dont know how to integrate as erst api?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to Spring Framework then you can use Java SDK or DocuSign has Rest API and documentation for API is available [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference).